# MySQL - Getting the position of a row in a result set

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT serverusers.serverID, serverusers.userID, serverusers.xpTotal, users.bot 
FROM users INNER JOIN serverusers ON users.userID = serverusers.userID 
WHERE users.bot = 'false' && serverID = 318467989655781389 
ORDER BY xpTotal DESC
```

I need to use this to find where in its "rank" a specific `userID` is. For example:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+----------+
 serverID | userID    | xpTotal    | bot      |
----------------------------------------------+
 50       | 23892     | 200        | false    |
----------------------------------------------+
 50       | 27173     | 180        | false    |
----------------------------------------------+
 50       | 17294     | 150        | false    |
----------------------------------------------+
 50       | 72973     | 110        | false    |
```

If I were to provide a `userID` of `17294`, it should return `3` because `17294` is the 3rd row.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff just added some

Comment: for MySQL > 8.0 `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY xpTotal DESC) AS Row#,` or                               `set @row_number=0;
select (@row_number := @row_number +1) as num,serverusers.serverID, serverusers.userID, serverusers.xpTotal, users.bot 
FROM users INNER JOIN serverusers ON users.userID = serverusers.userID 
WHERE users.bot = 'false' && serverID = 318467989655781389 
ORDER BY xpTotal DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a simple way uses variables:

```
SELECT suu.*
FROM (SELECT su.serverID, su.userID, su.xpTotal, u.bot,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM users u INNER JOIN
           serverusers su
          ON u.userID = su.userID CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT @rn := 0) params
      WHERE u.bot = 'false' AND su.serverID = 318467989655781389 
      ORDER BY xpTotal DESC
     ) suu
WHERE userID = ?;
```

The most recent versions of MySQL process the variable in the `SELECT` before the `ORDER BY`.  So, you might need an additional layer of subquery:

```
SELECT suu.*
FROM (SELECT su.serverID, su.userID, su.xpTotal, u.bot,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      FROM (SELECT su.serverID, su.userID, su.xpTotal, u.bot
            FROM users u INNER JOIN
                 serverusers su
                 ON u.userID = su.userID
            WHERE u.bot = 'false' AND su.serverID = 318467989655781389 
            ORDER BY xpTotal DESC
           ) suu CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     ) suu
WHERE userID = ?;
```